# json + jquery ajax populate option

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, loops

I must populate option data inside html tag using json, but i'm not sure how exactly pass the data.

THE JSON

```
[{"citta_provincia":"AGRIGENTO - ARAGONA","comune":"ARAGONA"},{"citta_provincia":"ALESSANDRIA - SAN MICHELE","comune":"SAN MICHELE"},{"citta_provincia":"ANCONA","comune":"ANCONA"}]
```

THE HTML

```
<select class="field-s mandatory" id="dedaler_city" name="dealer_city">                                     
<option selected>Scegli...</option>
</select>
```

THE JAVASCRIPT

```
    $cittasel = $('#dedaler_city');
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://path-to-json.json",
        dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function(data) {
            var parsa = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(parsa, function(key, value) {
                    $cittasel.html("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "'</option>'");
                }); 
            },
        error:function(){
        $cittasel.html('<option id="-1">not aviable</option>');
      }     
    });
```

i need to know how to pass the value to populate option fields, anybody could help me?

Comment: P.s. i want only the citta_provincia value!

Comment: uhm. `dataType: 'HTML'` and then `$.parseJSON(data)`? that makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

in the html, add a class to the dropdown

```
    CssClass="widget-dropdown-Ajax-Postback"
```

Use JQuery in your javascript for an ajax dropdown

```
    var ajaxtsddropdown = $("select.widget-dropdown-Ajax-Postback");
    if (ajaxtsddropdown.length > 0) {
    ajaxtsddropdown.removeClass("gvi-widget-dropdown-Ajax-Postback");
    ajaxtsddropdown.ajaxdropdown(
    {
        url: "/AjaxHelp/GetItems"
    });
    ajaxtsddropdown.on("ajaxdropdownselect", function (event, data) {
        if (data.select.val()) {
            $("#ajaxSelected").val(data.select.val());
            data.select.change();
        }
    });
    }
```

This will select the change and go to a json file to render the info. 
In an Ajax Controller, add

```
    public JsonResult  GetItems()
    {
    return Json(Controller.GetDropDownItems(),   
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

In the code behind, call the class

```
    if (CustomPostBack)
    {
    DropDown.CssClass = "widget-dropdown-Ajax-Postback";
    }
```

this will then call the json.

The json call will then go to your controller and retrieve your items however you want to retrieve them ( a service call, entity framework, etc). this data will be passed back to your dropdown

if you have a service setup, call the service. Otherwise, replace the service with entity framework and loop through your database.

```
    public static ListItem[] GetDropDownItems()
    {

        var list = new List<ListItem>();

        List<ItemsofInterest> itemsofInterest= new List<ItemsofInterest>();
        ServiceAdapter.InvokeService(ser => { itemsofInterest= ser.GetItemsofInterest(); });

        var items = itemsofInterest.Select(cd => cd.itemNumber).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            ListItem currentItem = new ListItem(itemNumber);
            list.Add(currentItem);
        }

        list.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select an item"));
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```